# Print element inside array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some problem to print elements inside array.

This is my Code

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log('antipasti', state.antipasti)
  return { antipasti: state.antipasti };
};

const ConnectedList = ({ antipasti }) => (
  <ul>
    {
      antipasti
        .filter(antipasto => !!antipasto )
        .map(antipasto => {
          console.log('antipasto', antipasto);
          <li>{antipasto.title}</li>
        })
    }
  </ul>
);

const List = connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedList);

export default List;
```

What I would to obtain:

I would to print the element inside state.antipasti, I have used the filter to not consider the undefined or null elements.

This `console.log('antipasto', antipasto);` prints:

```
antipasto {title: "Prova"}title: "Prova"__proto__: Object
```

so I have thought to use antipasto.title to obtain the title, but nothing appears.

I have imported this page, in another parent page only with

Comment: `return (<li>{antipasto.title}</li>)` You forgot to return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   {
      antipasti
        .filter(antipasto => !!antipasto )
        .map(antipasto => {
          console.log('antipasto', antipasto);
          <li>{antipasto.title}</li>
        })
    }
```

When you do `antipasto => { <li /> }` like that, you're not actually RETURNING anything to your `.map` function. In general, the React structure looks more like this

```
   {
      antipasti
        .filter(antipasto => !!antipasto )
        .map(antipasto => (<li>{antipasto.title}</li>)
    }
```

You may also be able to explicitly return inside the function, like Yury suggests in your comments, but that's not as common of a pattern and you'd only be doing it to support your `console.log` statement.